# Finding parameter such that probability of one random variable being greater than other is greather than a value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I recently encountered this problem online; I discussed it with my colleagues and we got several doubts so I would like to know your opinion.

It goes like this:

A control machine measures two independent random variables, $X_1, X_2$, both with uniform distribution, with $1\leq X_1\leq9$ and $1\leq X_2\leq a$. The machine works properly when $X_1<4X_2^2$. Find the value of $a$ such that $Pr(X_1<4X_2^2)\geq 0.99$.

I found density functions for both $X_1, X_2$, and thought that if $a>X_2>\frac{3}{2}$ then the condition holds, so we got to add up the probability that $a>X_2>\frac{3}{2}$ and the probability of {$1<X_2<\frac{3}{2}$}$\cap${$X_1<4X_2^2$}.

However, we do not know if $a>\frac{3}{2}$ so there lies our doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

$$4A^2 = 9 \iff A^2 = (9/4) \iff A = (3/2).$$

You are looking to calculate the probability that $X_1 < 4(X_2)^2$ when $X_2$ is allowed to run from $1$ through $a$.

For a specific value of $a$, you have to consider two cases:

- either $X_2 \leq (3/2)$
- or $X_2 > (3/2)$.

The 2nd case above is eliminated if $a \leq (3/2)$, so I am going to make the **complicating assumption** that $a > (3/2)$.  For situations where $a < (3/2)$ you should be able to simplify the analysis accordingly.

For a specific value of $X_2$, if $X_2 > (3/2)$ then the probability that $X_1$ is small enough is $100\%$.  That is, any value of $X_1$ in the range $[1,9]$ will be satisfactory.

---

At this point, I consider it helpful to stretch intuition, by looking at a specific example.

Suppose that $a = 2$.

Since you are having $X_2$ run from $1$ thru $2$, exactly $50\%$ of the time, the probability that $X_1$ will be satisfactory will be $100\%$.

Consider the specific case where $a = 2,$ and you are looking at $X_2 = 1.4.$  Then, $4(X_2)^2 = 4 \times 1.96 = 7.84.$

This means that in the specific situation that $X_2 = 1.4$, the probability that $(X_1)$ is satisfactory will be

$$\frac{7.84 - 1}{9 - 1}.$$

---

So, you have two probability functions to consider.

When $X_2 \leq (3/2)$, then the probability function will be given by

$$\frac{4(X_2)^2 - 1}{9-1} = \frac{4(X_2)^2 - 1}{8}.$$

When $X_2 > (3/2)$, then the probability function will be given by

$$\frac{9-1}{9-1} = 1.$$

Therefore, for a given value of $a$, the probability that $X_1$ will be satisfactory is

$$\frac{\int_1^{(3/2)} \frac{4(t_2)^2 - 1}{8}dt + \int_{3/2}^a (1)dt}{\int_1^a (1)dt}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the denominator is used simply to *normalize* the fraction.  That is, if the probability function throughout the interval was $(1)$, then you would want the overall fraction to evaluate as $(1)$.

So, you simply evaluate (1) above, as a function of $a$.  Then, you choose the value of $a > (3/2)$ (if any) such that this value exactly equals $(0.99)$.

Then, rinse and repeat, under the simplifying (**alternative**) assumption that $a < (3/2)$.  Then, you have (**at most**) two different answers, depending on whether $a$ is or is not $< (3/2)$.

---

**Edit**
Actually, the last two paragraphs above represented me departing from my anti-formality / pro-intuition religion.  It seems clear to me that as $a$ goes from $(1)$ to $\infty$ that the corresponding probability is increasing.  Therefore, if a value of $a$ is found that fulfills the requirement where $a > (3/2)$, then you are done.

Comment: Wow, that was a really explicative post, thank you!! If I am correct, $a>\frac{3}{2}$ gives $a=\frac{53}{3}$ while $a<\frac{3}{2}$ gives none (solution was unique according to the source that would make sense)

Comment: @PedroGarcía See the editing that I just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Just saw it, that seems clear to me too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the clean way would be to solve

$$0.99\leq P(\{X_1<4X_2^2\})=\int_1^{9}\int_{0.5\sqrt{x_1}}^a\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{a-1} dx_2dx_1$$

for $a$ by calculating the integral.

Maybe I don't understand your question, but of course you cannot assume something and show then that (under your assumption) your assumption holds.

Edit: I guess I indeed misunderstood the question, sorry, you could calculate the probability $P(X_1<4X_2^2)$ for $a=1.5$ (inserting in the integral above for example) and since $P(X_1<4X_2^2)$ is increasing in $a$ you know that there is no solution $a<1.5$ if $a=1.5$ is no solution. Then the integral "is well defined" since $0.5\sqrt{x_1}\leq1.5$

Comment: But that would lead to one equation with two parameters if I am not mistaken.

Comment: you integrate over $x_1$ and $x_2$ so it is only $a$ left

Comment: And how can you asume $a>\sqrt{x_1}/2$?

Comment: Yes I see your problem now, indeed one should show that.

Comment: You could calculate the probability $P(X_1<4X_2^2)$ for $a=1.5$ and since this is increasing in $a$ you know that there is no solution if $a=1.5$ is no solution